# Why is the query time of my PostgreSQL DB so much slower than in my MySQL DB?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, query-performance, postgis

I've been testing the performance of my PGSQL DB and MySQL DB with around a million entries and I've come to the conclusion that MySQL seems to execute my queries much faster, but I feel it should be the other way around and that I'm missing something.

I was also trying the query with and without Postgis functions (for example ST_DistanceSphere), and the queries with Postgis functions were slower, which also suprises me since I'd assume that Postgis would be faster.

The queries I'm trying to optimize are for finding the distance between two points using longitude and latitude.

I've created an index for the geom (geometry) column in PGSQL because i thought that might improve the performance, but it still only performs sequential scans, even if the query returns only around 5-10% of the database entries.

Both DBs have the same data inside of them.
Below I've attached images of the queries and their time to execute and an explain analyze.

[Query 1 PGSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVvy3.png) (Fastest, without using Postgis Functions)

```
WITH users_filtered AS (
SELECT id, pseudonym, city, (6371 * acos( 
                cos( radians(users.latitude) ) 
              * cos( radians( 49.5099 ) ) 
              * cos( radians( 6.74549 ) - radians(users.longitude) ) 
              + sin( radians(users.latitude) ) 
              * sin( radians( 49.5099 ) )
        ) ) as distance_in_km
FROM users
)
SELECT * FROM users_filtered;

"Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..124501.90 rows=1029033 width=29) (actual time=0.032..932.905 rows=1030000 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=80768"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=361"
"Planning Time: 1.697 ms"
"Execution Time: 984.460 ms"
```

[Query 2 PGSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5s5c.png) (Slowest, with Postgis functions)

```
WITH users_filtered AS (
SELECT id, pseudonym, city, ST_DistanceSphere(
    CAST(point(49.5099, 6.74549) AS geometry),
    users.geom
) AS distance_in_m
FROM users
)
SELECT * FROM users_filtered;

"Gather  (cost=1000.00..10909130.85 rows=1029033 width=29) (actual time=3.739..2583.961 rows=1030000 loops=1)"
"  Workers Planned: 2"
"  Workers Launched: 2"
"  Buffers: shared hit=81778"
"  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..10805227.55 rows=428764 width=29) (actual time=2.096..2147.072 rows=343333 loops=3)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=81778"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=19"
"Planning Time: 0.577 ms"
"Execution Time: 2696.416 ms"
```

[Query 3 PGSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXrWX.png) (Middle, with Postgis functions)

```
WITH users_filtered AS (
    SELECT id, pseudonym, city, ST_DistanceSphere(
        CAST(point(49.5099, 6.74549) AS geometry),
        users.geom
    ) AS distance_in_m
    FROM users
    WHERE ST_DWithin(users.geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(49.5099, 6.7454),4326), 200000)
)
SELECT * FROM users_filtered;

"Gather  (cost=1000.00..10806234.80 rows=103 width=29) (actual time=1.526..2071.394 rows=1030000 loops=1)"
"  Workers Planned: 2"
"  Workers Launched: 2"
"  Buffers: shared hit=81674"
"  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..10805224.50 rows=43 width=29) (actual time=1.336..1752.659 rows=343333 loops=3)"
"        Filter: st_dwithin(geom, '0101000020E61000007E1D386744C14840ECC039234AFB1A40'::geometry, '200000'::double precision)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=81674"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=23"
"Planning Time: 1.169 ms"
"Execution Time: 2161.133 ms"
```

[Query 1 MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzrM1.png) (Fastest, this exact same query takes 4-5s in PGSQL)

```
SELECT id, pseudonym, city, ROUND(111.045 *
          degrees(acos(cos(radians(49.5099)) *
          cos(radians(users.latitude)) *
          cos(radians(6.74549) -
          radians(users.longitude)) +
          sin(radians(49.5099)) *
          sin(radians(users.latitude)
          )
        )
      )
    ) AS distance_in_km FROM users;

'-> Table scan on users  (cost=272574.70 rows=2515667) (actual time=0.121..1023.582 rows=1030000 loops=1)\n'
```

[Query 2 MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoJxk.png) (Slowest, using [ST_Distance_Sphere](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere))

```
SELECT id, pseudonym, city, ST_Distance_Sphere(
    point(49.5099, 6.74549),
    point(users.latitude, users.longitude)
) AS distance_in_m FROM users;

'-> Table scan on users (cost=272574.70 rows=2515667) (actual time=0.096..1073.000 rows=1030000 loops=1)\n'
```

[Query 3 MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p29p5.png) (Middle)

```
SELECT id, pseudonym, city, (6371 * acos( 
                cos( radians(users.latitude) ) 
              * cos( radians( 49.5099 ) ) 
              * cos( radians( 6.74549 ) 
              - radians(users.longitude) ) 
              + sin( radians(users.latitude) ) 
              * sin( radians( 49.5099 ) )
        ) ) as distance_in_km
FROM users ORDER BY distance_in_km ASC;

'-> Sort: (6371 * acos((((cos(radians(users.latitude)) * cos(radians(49.5099))) * cos((radians(6.74549) - radians(users.longitude)))) + (sin(radians(users.latitude)) * sin(radians(49.5099))))))  (cost=272574.70 rows=2515667) (actual time=2142.974..2268.429 rows=1030000 loops=1)\n    -> Table scan on users  (cost=272574.70 rows=2515667) (actual time=0.141..1003.752 rows=1030000 loops=1)\n'
```

Does anyone know why PGSQL seems to be so much slower than MySQL, and even more so with the usage of Postgis functions?
I'd appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: "*if the query returns only around 5-10% of the database entries.*"  - none of the queries in your question are filtering rows. They always retrieve all 1.3 million rows

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes these queries return all the rows, but i've tested it and it had no difference on the result, the speed difference was still the same and a sequential scan was still being performed.

Comment: Well, the query that does use a WHERE clause does not filter out any rows either (despite the WHERE)

Comment: Yes but that's not my point, im not trying to filter out anything to get all the rows and see the execution time for the worst case scenario. (when all rows get selected)

Comment: Sorry your question doesn't make a lot of sense. You say "*I've created an index for the geom (geometry) column in PGSQL because i thought that might improve the performance, but it still only performs sequential scans, even if the query returns only around **5-10%** of the database entries.*" But you provided queries that are processing **all rows**, not 5-10%, so of course you'll get sequential scans, and therefore indexing won't really make much difference. Also please note that there's no such thing as performance differences between DB systems, the differences come from how you architect.

Comment: Would Postgres run faster without the "WITH"?  That is, using simple SELECTs as you did with MySQL?

Comment: How do I turn `actual time=0.121..1023.582` into seconds?

Comment: Your 3rd query is capable of using an index, but maybe it just chooses not to because all points are with in 20,000 degrees of all other points so there isn't much point in doing so.  Maybe you want the column to be a geography rather than a geometry, so that it uses meters rather than degrees.